# Why registering two identical attached properties works in Silverlight but fails in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties

Look at this code:

```
var property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "SomeAttachedProperty",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(View),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

var sameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "SomeAttachedProperty",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(View),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));
```

The second registration fails in WPF with `AgrumentException` that says "property already registered" (which is correct).

In decompiled sources of WPF `DependencyProperty` I found:

```
FromNameKey key = new FromNameKey(name, ownerType);
lock (Synchronized) 
{ 
     if (PropertyFromName.Contains(key))
     { 
          throw new ArgumentException(SR.Get(SRID.PropertyAlreadyRegistered,
                                      name, ownerType.Name));
     }
}
```

But in SL I haven't found any checks for existing properties with same name and type.

So the question is why SL doesn't check it but WPF does? Are there some basic limitations or what?

Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, your dependency property registration is wrong. The third argument to Register or RegisterAttached (`ownerType`) must be the class that registers the property, i.e. that contains the property declaration. It must not be FrameworkElement. See the example code in [RegisterAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495.aspx)

Comment: @Clemens, shame on me :) It really was a user control, but in the test project I write `FrameworkElement`. Anyway, the same thing happens.

Comment: I guess in SL calling RegisterAttached a second time with all the same parameters might just return the same DependencyProperty instance. Have you checked that?

Comment: @Clemens, yes, they are different.

Comment: Well, Silverlight is not WPF, and the WPF API documentation for [RegisterAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495.aspx) does not explicitly mention any exception that is thrown when the property is already registered. In the end it is an implementation detail. You should perhaps ask Microsoft why they implemented it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration of an attached dependency property is incomplete without the static Get and Set accessors, and even in Silverlight you can't write them twice in the same class.

```
class MayClass
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomethingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "Something", typeof(object), typeof(MyClass));

    // required
    public static object GetSomething(UIElement element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(SomethingProperty );
    }

    // required
    public static void SetSomething(UIElement element, object value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SomethingProperty , value);
    }
}
```